# How To Compensate For Margin From Control.PointToScreen?

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates

I'm using .PointToScreen(Point.Empty); to determine the location of controls relative to my entire screen.  The only problem that I'm facing is that the coordinates are always off by a little if they're inside of a form.  It seems to me that what's happening is that the form's margin is not accounted for and causes this error.

http://min.us/mvnZhCJ

I'm using this to take screenshots of entire forms or controls inside of the form.  When I do a full form screenshot, what happens is that the margins are again not accounted for.  The coordinates given by .PointToScreen(Point.Empty); is the top left corner of the form, but it's inside of the form so when I take a screenshot from this point, it goes past the right and bottom border.

Is there an automatic built-in way to fix this or do I have to manually compensate for this margin error?

```
static public void PrintForm(Control form) {
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
    g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    g.CopyFromScreen(form.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X, form.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y, 0, 0, new Size(form.Width, form.Height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrintPage += (sender, e) => Document_PrintImage(e, image);
    document.Print(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Forms Bounds property. This provides the rectangle which it occupies on the screen.

For an individual control you can use the Parent.RectangleToScreen( Bounds ) to get the screen rectangle.

This will include all stuff within the bounds of the control.

Comment: +1 - This works.  Also, instead of `Bounds` you may just want to use `Left` and `Top`.  I don't like how you need a special case for whether the `Control` is actually a top-level `Form`, though.  Not sure if there's any way around that.

Comment: Would I have to create special cases for child elements, grand child elements, great grand child elements etc?

Comment: If you're simply copying pixels from the screen to your image then this will include any visible elements within the specified form or control. You shouldn't need do anything special for child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the form's [ClientRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx) and [ClientSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) properties for this purpose.